# Java and Synchronization issues

Tags: java, multithreading, class, concurrency

I am writing a program in Java and I am a bit worried about synchronization.

The scenario is pretty "simple" we have a simple bank account class where multiple people can withdraw money from accounts (they **can not** deposit though) they can also check the balance of the account. The thing is that the balance changes all the time so we want the customers to view the correct balance!

Here is my class so far.

```
    class Account implements Serializable {

    private boolean available = false;

    String ac_id;
    String name;
    int balance;

    public Account(String ac_id, String name, int blnc)

    {
        this.ac_id = ac_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.blnc = blnc;

    }

    public synchronized int getMoney(int money) {
        if (money > blnc) {
            return -1;
        }
        while (available == true) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        blnc -= money;
        available = true;
        notifyAll();
        return 1;
    }

    public synchronized int chkBalance() {

        return blnc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()

    {
        return "Balance: " + chkBalance();
    }

}
```

As you can see with this implementation I can ensure that someone can get money from one account object , but then this account object is blocked , then one solution is at

```
public synchronized int chkBalance()
```

method to add `available = false;` which seems to solve my problem, but I really cant say if this is correct, I mean if they are indeed synchronized and customers see the correct balance.

Thanks in advance!!

P.S. Theoretically, if I just used the synchronized word before each of these two methods, wouldn't be alright? I mean, only one thread would occupy each method at a time and since there is no need for deposits what is the point in using Boolean available true/false ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need available boolean at all. It's enough to synchronize only getMoney method and make blnc volatile so other threads checking for changes will be able to see them. Try something like:

```
class Account implements Serializable {

final String ac_id;
final String name;
volatile int blnc;

public Account(String ac_id, String name, int blnc) {
    this.ac_id = ac_id;
    this.name = name;
    this.blnc = blnc;
}

public synchronized int getMoney(int money) {
    if (money > blnc) {
        return -1;
    }
    blnc -= money;
    return 1;
}

public int chkBalance() {
    return blnc;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Balance: " + chkBalance();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned with the speed of execution, then all you need to do is make the methods synchronized.  This will guarantee that each method of one particular account object is only accessed by one thread at a time.  Your `available` flag doesn't appear useful in your implementation.  There is also no point in putting `wait()` inside a synchronized method; this can only slow down other threads that are waiting for the object's lock.

It is particularly important that `getMoney()` be synchronized, because this method changes the value of `blnc`, and failing to synchronize it could result in two threads overwriting the value simultaneously, in which case one thread would fail to take effect.

In your implementation, it doesn't much matter if `chkBalance()` is synchronized because it does not write to `blnc`.  If this method is called concurrently with `getMoney()`, it will either return the value of `blnc` before or after the change is made to `blnc`, and this scheduling is beyond programmer control.

It is also useful not to synchronize `chkBalance()` because you may have many simultaneous calls to `chkBalance()` from different threads, and there is no point in these calls waiting on each other.

To ensure that you are getting the latest value of `blnc` from shared memory, and not a locally cached value, consider making the `blnc` variable volatile.

Answer (score 0):

> ... multiple people can withdraw money from accounts [and] they can also check the balance ...[but], the balance changes all the time so we want the customers to view the correct balance!

You can't.  If other people (threads) can withdraw money at any time, then there is no such thing as *the* correct balance.  The best you can guarantee is *a* correct balance.  That is, with proper synchronization, you can ensure that the number returned by checkBalance() *was* correct at some point in the past.

Here's the problem.  Some function fubar() calls checkBalance().  Why?  Why does it care what the balance is?  As soon as checkBalance() returns, the calling thread is no longer synchronized.  Any other thread could potentially make a withdrawal between the time when checkBalance() returned, and the time when fubar() does something with the information.

If fubar() needs to know the balance in order to *do* something with the information, then fubar() needs to be synchronized too.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are mixing things here :

- getMoney is synchronized, so only 1 thread will get in at each time
- when the available flag is true, you put the thread in wait, until someone calls notify (which you do yourself, in the same thread as it is synchronized)

Why are you mixing wait/notify and synchronized? Since the method is synchronized, no other thread will be in wait.. they will be blocking on the entry of the method.

To be honest, unless you add more logic to it, synchronization is not really usefull here : in your getMoney you only do an assignment to the balance. The chckBalance method is either executed just before, or just after... you never risk having dirty values anyway.

Comment: I agree mostly.  Some sort of synchronization is necessary around the line `blnc -= money;`.  Otherwise, if two threads execute that line at the same time, one will not have an effect.

Comment: *In your getMoney you only do an assignment to the balance*: Not at all: the code checks the balance, and then decrements it if authorized. This is a typical check-then-act operation that is not atomic and thus requires synchronization. Without synchronization, 2 concurrent threads might each withdraw 1000 from an account having 1500, which is exactly wat the method tries to avoid.

Comment: @JBNizet hey thanks for input, do you just agree that the simple synchronized word is enough before getMoney() and nothing else? Also about chkBalance() we don't need synchronization, just volatile for the value. That was my initial thoughts but I need some kind of confirmation, if you can :D

Comment: Yes, I agree, although using volatile instead of synchronizing the `checkBalance()` method looks like a fragile, premature optimization. If the `getMoney()` method modifies the balance twice, you'll have a bug: `checkBalance()` will return an intermediary balance value.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. So a work around for this possible bug would be the use of synchronized with volatile for checkBalance(), or it isn't possible to use both of them ? To be honest I don't see how the getMoney() method would modify the balance twice if it is synchronized, or I am missing something. I feel like it is a trade-off here. If I take the volatile way, many clients would be able to see the resource simultaneously with the risk of bug, while with synchronized we'll have more "stable" results. Although, I am still not convinced about the bug you describe. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: synchronized is sufficient. As long as every access to shared state is synchronized on the same lock, using volatile is useless. Suppose that `getMoney()` decrements the balance, and then decrements it again to charge 1% of bank commissions. The `checkBalance()` method could see the balance after the first decrement, but before the second one. If you make the checkBalance() method synchronized, that won't happen.